# ARIMA Modelling in R vs MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

I tried to fit a time series data for MATLAB and in R.
Here's the code for both

MATLAB

```
model = arima(3,0,2)
fit = estimate(model,Price_DLR)
```

R

```
arima(Price_DLR, order = c(3,0,2))
```

I am getting different results for both of these. Which one is correct ?

I used logarithmic returns of brent oil prices (I didn't know how to attach the data)

The results are (just for info)

MATLAB

```
                             Standard          t     
 Parameter       Value          Error       Statistic 
-----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
 Constant    3.18693e-05   3.50447e-05       0.909388
    AR{1}        1.83843     0.0295341        62.2478
    AR{2}      -0.995256     0.0300321       -33.1397
    AR{3}      0.0352115    0.00950566        3.70426
    MA{1}       -1.81037     0.0274665       -65.9118
    MA{2}       0.929497       0.02484        37.4194
 Variance    0.000535556   3.79527e-06        141.111
```

R

```
Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2      ar3      ma1      ma2  intercept
      0.2533  0.2715  -0.0318  -0.2232  -0.2918      3e-04
s.e.  0.3326  0.2649   0.0139   0.3328   0.2611      3e-04

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0005366:  log likelihood = 15421.43,  aic = -30828.87
```

Comment: Why can't they both be correct?

Comment: How can  both be correct ? I tried AR(3) for both. They seem to have the same answer. but for ARMA(3,2) they have different coefficients altogether.

Comment: The R function has many additional arguments that control various aspects of the fitting procedure and model. I presume the matlab version does as well. Isn't it possible that they are simply using different default values or optimization algorithms or fitting procedures. I highly doubt either of them is "wrong".

Comment: oh.. but if u see the MATLAB thing the t values are way off the critical values whereas in R the t values are close to critical values.. There seems to be a lot of diff.. I thought all the programs predict more or less the same coefficients.. so which one to pick ??